# How to use my own version of Apache codecs in Android Studio with libGDX and RoboVM?

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx, build.gradle

I have tried to import *Apache Commons Codec 1.8* via Maven and I have tried to import *Apache Commons Codec 1.10* as a jar library into my libGDX project.

When I use a class of it (`Base64`) in my code, the class name turns red. Then when I choose "import class", Android Studio offers me only `libcore.io.Base64` and two android classes.

When I manually import `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` and then click on `Base64` (holding cmd key), I get `robovm-rt-sources.jar/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64` opened. In my `build.gradle` I actually use "exclude module" for preventing that:

```
compile("org.robovm:robovm-rt:${roboVMVersion}")  {
    exclude module: "org.apache.commons.codec.*"
}
```

How can I force Android Studio to use an actual version of `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`?